# EGR fault replaced twice now replaced with new peugeot part and the fault can not be cleared

Tags: egr

I have a peugeot expert van 2007, i have had a few issues with new EGR valve failing so on the 1st march 2019 i had a new genuine Peugeot part fitted and the garage could not get the engine management light to reset I have tried disconnecting the battery and reconnecting it and start the engine and after a few mins it comes back on, the garage dont know why it will not clear

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the exact code?

Comment: What fault codes do you have? What engine? Any other symptoms apart from the engine light?

Comment: There could be another part at fault or a wiring issue? The codes may help...